# How can I make this image href to index page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this image a href, its like this because I couldn't figure out how to have the image align with the menu on the right. But now I'm trying to make the logo go to the front page, I have tried making the code `<div class="wrapper"> <div href="index.html" class="picture1"></div>` but that doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix this

```css
div.picture1 {
   width:153px; 
   height:60px;
   background-image:url('Carlsberglogof.png');
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="picture1"></div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieZC1.png)

Comment: Use anchor instead, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a make it display block

Comment: Where will I inset it in the code, I tried but I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your div with an anchor tag. I added the green colour so you can see it.

```css
a {
   display: block;
   width: 153px;
   height: 60px;
   background-image:url('Carlsberglogof.png'); 
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="yourURL" class="picture1"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use JavaScript, for example:

```
<div onClick="location.href='/index.html'"> ...
```

...or simply wrap the whole element in an <a> tag:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="index.html">
    <div class="picture1"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```